# Остен, острый, сдобен, добрый, бдение, бодрый

Tags: этимология

Можно ли отнести букву Р в таких словах, как: *острый, добрый, бодрый, мокрый, пёстрый, зубр, дубрава, сторица, гореть*, — к этимологическому суффиксу существительных *остен, сдоба, бдение, моча, писание, зуб, дуб, сто и огонь*?

Comment: А) вы о чем? Б) называя слова с разными суффиксами, вы ожидаете, что чудом они могут оказаться одним? откуда вообще такая идея?

Comment: @Aer ну существуют ведь исторические суффиксы -б(а),-в(а),-г(а),-д(а),-т(а). Почему бы и нет?

Comment: Почему бы и нет _что_? Каким образом вы полагаете все эти совершенно разные буковки одним и тем же?

Comment: @Aer бдение и бодрый этимологически однокоренные?

Comment: задайте вопрос. Здесь мы обсуждаем суффиксы.

Comment: @Aer являетя ли "р" в слове бодрый этимологическим суффиксом?

Comment: вероятно, является.

Answer (score 2):

> Можно ли отнести букву "р" в таких прилагательных как острый, добрый,
>   бодрый, мокрый к этимологическому суффиксу

В русском языке - нет. этот "суффикс наследуется из праславянского, а в нем, вероятно из ПИЕ напрямую. В таких случаях считается, что в языке-приемнике (русском) оригинальный морф уже не членим. 
Кстати, в данном контексте я бы вообще избегал избегал терминов наподобие "этимологический суффикс", поскольку суффикс уже не выделяется в принципе, ибо совершенно утеряна его семантика.