# Пить -> пир, пировать

Tags: этимология

Что это за странный словообразовательный элемент "р", почему он присутствует только в слове пир?

Относится ли "р" в обозначенных по ссылке ниже словах к тому же словообразовательному элементу? [бдеть -> бодр](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448762/%D0%9E%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9)